# Why am I getting a "session could not be started with the iPad" error when syncing?

Tags: itunes, ipad, mac, data-synchronization, backup

This morning while trying to sync my iPad I started getting the following error from iTunes:

- iTunes could not backup iPad because a session could not be started with the iPad

I've tried the following:

- Deleting the iPhoto cache "com.apple.iPhoto.plist" (might be corrupt)
- Running the Repair Disk Permissions from Disk Utility
- Delete existing backup (might be corrupt)
- Backing it up to a new account (same Mac)
- Different sync cable
- Different USB port
- Rebooting the Mac and the iPad
- Turning off Photo sync

So far, no luck. Still getting the error when trying to sync or backup my iPad. The iPhone 4 syncs fine. Running Verify Disk Permissions after the Repair still reported issues, but none of them seemed to be in any directories related to iTunes (all Java related).

FYI, it starts trying to backup, but fails at around 90%. So it would seem it has a "session started", but fails part way through.

**UPDATE**: I was listening to Pandora while my iPad charged and functioned as my AirDisplay when all of a sudden my iPad started rebooting repeatedly (not syncing or updating, checked iTunes.) It kept rebooting until I removed the sync cable. When it came back then it backed-up and synced fine. I'll leave this question open in case someone has any suggestions. If no one has any suggestions then I will probably delete it.

Comment: okay the same happened to me on the i-pod touch, it happened to me twice. the first time i got the message and i synced it again and it worked. Now i am trying to sync it and it says the same thing!!! It's strange because my ipod photo chache isnt working but i still have the pictures on my regular files. I really dont know what to do, hopefully tomorrow it will work!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Stackexchange is not like other forums. Answers to questions should actually attempt to answer the question. Otherwise, remarks such as this should be entered as a comment. I am going to convert your answer to a comment for the question itself. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I cabled my iPhone and synced. After doing that, I unchecked the sync using Wi-Fi. I then applied the change. Then, I checked sync using Wi-Fi and unplugged my phone. I then synced using Wi-Fi. It worked for me. Hope it does for someone else.

Comment: Mine started working again after something similar. I think the solution is to just keep kicking it until it works.

Answer (score 1):

This happened again, and here are the steps I took:

1. Delete existing backup
2. Restart iTunes
3. Restart iPad
4. Sync

It seems to be caused by canceling the sync during the backup. I might try it again to see if those are the steps to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted iPod photo cache. No change.
I performed iPad hard reset. No change.
I pulled up applications menu (double menu button click) and then clicked the "minus" icon for every single App until they were all removed from the list.
Sync then worked perfectly.
The problem appeared to be that backups were being prevented by one of the Apps I had "open" in the background.

Comment: That could be. I thought I tried rebooting the iPad before, which should have accomplished the same thing. If I get it again I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too but I found out it was caused by stopping a backup in progress. To solve, just quit iTunes completely and power off your iPad, then relaunch iTunes and turn your iPad back on.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that when this message "iTunes could not backup iPad because a session could not be started with the iPad" popped out, your itunes was actually backing up/restoring from your back up data. It happened to me also, then my ipad suddenly rebooted and then it was restored from the backup data

Comment: Could be. It is doing it again now. Wish I knew what fixed it last time so I could fix it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are items I've seen cause this:

1. The device is not working properly. Shutting it down with a slide to power off usually remedies this temporary situation on the device.
2. ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
3. ~/Library/Lockdown
4. /private/var/db/lockdown

Do be sure to make a backup before deleting files from locations 2-4 and I like to delete them and then reboot the mac to allow the programs to recreate the lockdown files as needed. You are removing all backups by deleting items from #2 above - use caution.